# 22.04: How to resolve "libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-2ubuntu4) but 1.12.20-3~devacom is to be installed"?

Tags: dependencies, compiling, ffmpeg, 22.04, dbus

I've been trying to compile a couple of things (ffmpeg, smooth) and I run into this dbus error.  It seems to be related to Ubuntu 22.04 because I did not have a problem compiling ffmpeg in 18.04 or 20.04.

```
$ apt install libgtk-3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-2ubuntu4) but 1.12.20-3~devacom is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ apt install libsdl2-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-2ubuntu4) but 1.12.20-3~devacom is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ apt install libdbus-1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-2ubuntu4) but 1.12.20-3~devacom is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add output of `apt policy libdbus-1-3` terminal command.

Comment: Just now for me "sudo apt-get update" solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dependency for `libdbus-1-dev` is `libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-2ubuntu4)` which means **exactly** version "1.12.20-2ubuntu4" it can not work with version "1.12.20-3~devacom".

Look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` where the "devacom" versions come from and remove it.

I guess you have a launchpad related to "devacom" from Ubuntu 20.04 still configured. Maybe this: [https://launchpad.net/~devacom](https://launchpad.net/%7Edevacom)

Answer (score 0):

add "libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.20-2) but 1.12.24-0+deb10u1 is to be installed" to the /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).